# When I read the guide Building REST services with Spring, I can't import javax packages for @entity table

Tags: java, spring

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFlnY.png)
I just use this and step by step with guides.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkaTe.png)
the guide told me what i wanan go ahead
I was reading the REST server setup process in the Spring documentation, and by the time I got to the first step it was no longer running.
this is the code of table

````java
package payroll;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class Employee {

private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
private String name;
private String role;

Employee() {}

Employee(String name, String role) {

    this.name = name;
    this.role = role;

}

public Long getId() {
return this.id;
}

public String getName() {
return this.name;
}

public String getRole() {
return this.role;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
this.role = role;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (this == o)
      return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Employee))
      return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, employee.id) && Objects.equals(this.name, employee.name)
        && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name, this.role);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Employee{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name='" + this.name + ''' + ", role='" + this.role + ''' + '}';
}
}```
````

Comment: Welcome! But I think the problem comes at compilation time, isn't it? Can you provide some compilation logs, near when the trouble happens? And maybe: a bit of your _Maven_ `pom.xml`, if it's the tool you're using?

Comment: Post text, not images. Images aren’t searchable.

Answer (score 0):

All the clues point in one direction: version changes. The old Spring documentation guide uses JavaX, which has quietly replaced Jakarta in the latest Spring, which is clearly a historical problem and the solution is simple. But it is not easy to spot this error. Thanks to Helen Scott.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/migrating-javax-jakarta/
We just have to go to the navigation menu to use the migration function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXshG.png)

Comment: Well I doubt it was quitely. It is clearly mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes) and the [migration guides](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#jakarta-ee). Next to that in several blog posts around the first milestones of Spring Boot 3 and Spring Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

The imports that replaced `javax` in version 3 of Spring boot are

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
```

instead of

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```

That means that any `javax` package from any dependency should be replaced with `jakarta` version.

jakarta packages are located in dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also, make sure that your parent Spring version is one and only version, do not mix Spring boot 3 with Spring Boot 2.